# How can I get the output of the "R" data() function to be placed in a vector?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the output of the R `data()` function into a vector. By default the output pops up in a new window. I can cut and paste the data but I was hoping to be able to do something like the following

```
stuff <- data()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can do `stuff <- data()` and it will work. `data()` can't be stored as a vector because it contains objects with different sizes, that's what `list`s for. If you'll do `typeof(stuff)` you will see it is a `list`. You can see what's in there using `lapply(stuff, print)` or `attributes(stuff)`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg . I was confused since print returns an "invisible" list. As an R newbie I didn't know about "invisible" return values and didn't understand why there was no output at the command line. I didn't even think to actually try stuff <- data() since I didn't see any output to capture (pretty lame on my part). Thanks for explaining. I was wondering how data() is able to redirect its output to a new window. I looked a the code for data but didn't see anything obvious. Can you explain quickly how it redirects its output to a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need names, it is very easy.
use this:

```
datasets.name <- c(data())$results
```

Comment: The functions `str`, `class`, and `names` are your best friends in R.